# EventKitで、eventIdentifier を取得したい。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

現在、swift2 で iOS用のカレンダーアプリを制作しています。

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
var calendar: EKCalendar!
var events: [EKEvent]?

func loadEvents()
{
    // Create a date formatter instance to use for converting a string to a date
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    // Create start and end date NSDate instances to build a predicate for which events to select
    let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-01-01")
    let endDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-12-31")

    if let startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate {
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()

        // Use an event store instance to create and properly configure an NSPredicate
        let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: nil)

        // Use the configured NSPredicate to find and return events in the store that match
        self.events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(eventsPredicate).sort(){
            (e1: EKEvent, e2: EKEvent) -> Bool in
            return e1.startDate.compare(e2.startDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
        }
    }

}
```

このようなコードでイベントの一覧を取得することができましたが、
イベントごとの固有のidentifierを取得することができません。

```
    // イベントが見つかった.
    if !events!.isEmpty {
        for i in events!{


                print(i.title)
                print(i.startDate)
                print(i.eventIdentifier)


        }
    }
```

このようなコードで、titleやstartDateはprintできまたのですが、
いろいろ試してみましたが、eventIdentifierはprintすることができませんでした。

この後、eventIdentifierを利用してイベントの管理（情報の取得や編集）をしたいのですが、
完全に行き詰まってしましました。

解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
どうか、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let eventStore = EKEventStore()を複数宣言しているのが原因でした。
へんな設定をしていたので、へんな動作をしていたようです。
idだけが取得できないのは、なにかの保護がはたらいていたのでしょうか？　よくわかりません。
ちゃんとした理由はなにひとつわかっていませんが、いちおう自己解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

そのような目的には、`calendarItemExternalIdentifier`というプロパティ(`EKEvent`の親クラスである`EKCalendarItem`のプロパティです)が使えるのではないかという話をAppleのDeveloper Forumsで見かけたことがあります。

[How to remove an existing Event from Apple Calendar](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/114479#114479)

[calendarItemExternalIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekcalendaritem/1507283-calendaritemexternalidentifier)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> var calendarItemExternalIdentifier: String { get }
> ```
>
> ### Discussion
>
> This identifier allows you to access the same event or reminder across
>   multiple devices.
>
> (以下略)
>
> この識別子は、あなたが複数のデバイス間で同一のイベントやreminderにアクセスすることができるようにします。

一度試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: let eventStore = EKEventStore()を複数宣言しているのが原因でした。calendarItemExternalIdentifierの使い方は、今から勉強したいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @Natsume さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。ご質問を書き込まれた方の中には、回答者にすごく気を使われる方がおられるわけですが、その「原因」からすると私の回答が「承認」されるのはちょっと変かなと思います。できればご自身で正解を投稿していただいてそちらをご承認ください。

Comment: Pere d'OOさん、すいませんでした。stack-overflow初心者でよくわかっていませんでした。